# Action.type undefined redux

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

No matter what I do, I can't get rid of the mistake. I have often rewritten the actions but the error remains. I also wrote thunk at the top of the createstore. It would be great if you could support me a little bit.

My action, nothing special here only a fetch call to get my players

```
import fetch from "cross-fetch"

export const SET_PLAYERS = "setplayers"
export const setPlayers = players => {
  return{
    type: "setplayers",
    players
  }
}

export const fetchPlayers = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  return fetch("http://localhost:4444/api/players")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(players => {
      dispatch(setPlayers(players))
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log("Could not fetch assortments" , err)
    })
}
```

Component, at this point in time only a dummy to invoke the action:

```
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import { fetchPlayers } from "./action"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import EnhancedTable from "../components/list/List"
import getPlayers from "./reducer"


class PlayerTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.fetchPlayers()
  }



  render() {
    console.log("#######", this.props.players)
    return (
      <EnhancedTable />
    )
  }
}

PlayerTable.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  players: getPlayers(state)
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchPlayers })(PlayerTable)
```

Reducer

```
import { SET_PLAYERS } from "./action"

const setPlayers = (state={}, action) => {
  console.log("ACTION", action)
  switch (action.type) {
  case SET_PLAYERS:
    return {...state, players: action.players}
  default:
    return state
  }
}
export default setPlayers

export const getPlayers = state => ([])
```

CombinedReducers

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux"
import { reducer as formReducer } from "redux-form"
import  showProgressbar  from "../components/progressbar/reducer"
import  showSnackBar from "../components/snackbar/reducer"
import  setPlayers from "../player/reducer"

export default combineReducers({
  form: formReducer,
  showProgressbar,
  showSnackBar,
  setPlayers
})
```

CreateStore

```
import App from "./App"
import React from "react"
import rootReducer from "./reducers"
import thunk from "redux-thunk"
import { render } from "react-dom"
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux"
import { Provider } from "react-redux"
import { createLogger } from "redux-logger"

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  compose(applyMiddleware(thunk),
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
))

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  /* eslint-disable*/
  document.getElementById("root")
  /* eslint-enable */
)
```

Comment: can you please add your action.js?

Comment: its the first one. My action

Comment: can you show more information about the error

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
    at setPlayers (reducer.js:17)
    at Function.mapStateToProps [as mapToProps] (List.js:71)
    at mapToPropsProxy (wrapMapToProps.js:48)

Answer (score 0):

You've defined `mapStateToProps` properly, but don't you need to do the same with `mapDispatchToProps` for the second argument to `connect()`?

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  players: getPlayers(state)
})

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  fetchPlayers() {
    dispatch(fetchPlayers())
  }
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PlayerTable)
```

Comment: unfortunately nothing changes when I write out the mapDispatchtoProps. I still getting this error